# How to calculate the processing time in rx

Tags: java, rx-java

For the following flow, I am wondering how I can calculate the time it takes to process all the data in forEach(...).

```
Observable
  .from(1,2,3)
  .flatMap(it - {})
  .toBlocking()
  .forEarch(it -> {//some paring logic here})
```

**EDIT**

After reading this tutorial: [Leaving the Monad](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/10_LeavingTheMonad.html#LeavingTheMonad), I feel the simple solution would be to do the following. Let me know if I missed something

```
List items = Observable
      .from(1,2,3)
      .flatMap(it - {})
      .toList();

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

for(Object it : items)
{
  //some parsing here
}

long processingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
```

Comment: This code is probably incorrect because `toList` already consumed the observable, so it'll be measuring only the for loop. If the production of values is always _cold data_ like `Observable.from`, `Observable.just`, `Observable.range` and always consumed immediately then it's possible to measure the whole thing. If you're interested only a part of the pipeline, then a clever code needs to be used.

Comment: @Brice you said "toList already consumed the observable, so it'll be measuring only the for loop." This is exactly what I am looking for. The for loop does some processing to each of the objects in the List. I want to calculate the time it took to perform the processing to those objects

Comment: Oh, then it's not that much related to Rx at all it seems. IMHO I find it kinda amiss to leave an `Observable`, for two reasons, **1.** most of the time what can be done in a `for loop` can be done with operators (`reduce` for example), `Observable` is a monad, a pipeline of action to do on data, io, etc. going back to regular Java is not the evil, but it feels out of place **2.** There much more than Java 8 streams (if the project is using Java 8) (yet Java 8 Streams are quite good at pure computation). That is a bit of proselytism, I know, but Rx is really nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this what you want, from your code I split the production of values `Observable.range` (that should match the `Observable.just` in your sample) and the pipeline to measure, in this case I added some fake computation.

The idea is to wrap the pipeline you want to measure in a flatmap and add a stopwatch in a single flatmap.

```
Observable.range(1, 10_000)
        .nest()
        .flatMap(
                o -> {
                    Observable<Integer> pipelineToMeasure = o.flatMap(i -> {
                        Random random = new Random(73);
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(random.nextInt(5));
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }
                        return Observable.just(i);
                    });

                    Stopwatch measure = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();
                    return pipelineToMeasure
                            .doOnSubscribe(measure::start)
                            .doOnTerminate(() -> {
                                measure.stop();
                                System.out.println(measure);
                            });
                }
        )
        .toBlocking()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Just to avoid confusion I used `nest` to avoid recreating myself the Observable in the outer flatmap.
Also I'm using the `Stopwatch` of the Guava library.

---

To give more information, here's a possible code to measure in the `forEach` statement when blocking.

```
MeasurableAction1<Integer> measuring = MeasurableAction1.measure(System.out::println);
Observable
        .just(1, 2, 3)
        .flatMap(Observable::just)
        .toBlocking()
        .forEach(measuring.start());

measuring.stop().elapsed(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And the measuring class :

```
private static class MeasurableAction1<T> implements Action1<T> {
    private Stopwatch measure = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();
    private Action1<? super T> action;

    public MeasurableAction1(Action1<? super T> action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public void call(T t) {
        action.call(t);
    }

    public MeasurableAction1<T> start() {
        measure.start();
        return this;
    }

    public MeasurableAction1<T> stop() {
        measure.stop();
        return this;
    }

    public long elapsed(TimeUnit desiredUnit) {
        return measure.elapsed(desiredUnit);
    }

    public static <T> MeasurableAction1<T> measure(Action1<? super T> action) {
        return new MeasurableAction1<>(action);
    }
}
```

---

And better without blocking with a subscriber, note that `.subscribe` offer more *options* that the `.forEach` alias (either when blocking or not):

```
    Observable
            .just(1, 2, 3)
            .flatMap(Observable::just)
            .subscribe(MeasuringSubscriber.measuringSubscriber(
                    System.out::println,
                    System.out::println,
                    System.out::println
            ));
```

And subscriber :

```
private static class MeasuringSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {
    private Stopwatch measure = Stopwatch.createUnstarted();
    private Action1<? super T> onNext;
    private final Action1<Throwable> onError;
    private final Action0 onComplete;

    public MeasuringSubscriber(Action1<? super T> onNext, Action1<Throwable> onError, Action0 onComplete) {
        this.onNext = onNext;
        this.onError = onError;
        this.onComplete = onComplete;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        try {
            onComplete.call();
        } finally {
            stopAndPrintMeasure();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        try {
            onError.call(e);
        } finally {
            stopAndPrintMeasure();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(T item) {
        onNext.call(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        measure.start();
        super.onStart();
    }

    private void stopAndPrintMeasure() {
        measure.stop();
        System.out.println("took " + measure);
    }

    private static <T> MeasuringSubscriber<T> measuringSubscriber(final Action1<? super T> onNext, final Action1<Throwable> onError, final Action0 onComplete) {
        return new MeasuringSubscriber<>(onNext, onError, onComplete);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting but seems complicated just to measure the time :-)

Comment: @Pangea Actually this is _inlined_ code there's however benefit to lay it out in a way to encapsulate the logic inside a method and/or an operator via `lift` (which makes it really readable.

Comment: What is nest() meant for?

Comment: I've made some edits after reading Leaving the Mondads article. Can you let me know if that provides me what I need and that it is simple

Comment: @Pangea Without `nest` I'd need to create an Observable form the item (an int here) inside the flatmap, with `nest` I can just use the Observable wrapped.

Comment: @Pangea I update the answer with more options to measure time.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to create an Observable which will output the timings. You can do this by wrapping your computation with `Observable#using`:

```
public class TimerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final PublishSubject<Long> timings = PublishSubject.create();

        final Observable<List<Integer>> list = Observable
                .just(1, 2, 3)
                .flatMap(TimerExample::longRunningComputation)
                .toList();

        final Observable<List<Integer>> timed
                = Observable.using(() -> new Timer(timings), (t) -> list, Timer::time);

        timings.subscribe(time -> System.out.println("Time: " + time + "ms"));

        List<Integer> ints = timed.toBlocking().last();
        System.out.println("ints: " + Joiner.on(", ").join(ints));

        ints = timed.toBlocking().last();
        System.out.println("ints: " + Joiner.on(", ").join(ints));
    }

    private static Observable<Integer> longRunningComputation(Integer i) {
        return Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).map(ignored -> i);
    }

    public static class Timer {
        private final long startTime;
        private final Observer<Long> timings;

        public Timer(Observer<Long> timings) {
            this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            this.timings = timings;
        }

        public void time() {
            timings.onNext(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        }
    }
}
```

The timings are in this case print to the console, but you can do with them as you please:

```
Time: 1089ms
ints: 2, 1, 3
Time: 1003ms
ints: 1, 3, 2
```